# Can I heal horror from an ally using Fearless?

Tags: arkham-horror-card-game

[Fearless](https://arkhamdb.com/card/01067) says:

> If this skill test is successful, heal 1 horror.

Does that mean that I can heal an ally too or it must from an investigator?

Answer (score 4):

No, it can only heal **your investigator** not other assets or investigators. Heal targets **your investigator** unless the card text **explicity** say "from an investigator at your location", "from an **Ally** asset", "from any card" or something like that. If it just says "Heal X horror/damage" then it refers only to your investigator.

From the [Official FFG FAQ v1.9 updated on June 2021](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/16/73/16736473-35f6-42e7-ac32-60811326865f/ahc_faq_v19_1.pdf):

> If a card effect says to heal damage or horror but does not indicate from where, can I use to heal assets or investigators other than myself?
>
> **No**. "Heal X damage/horror" is short hand for "Heal X damage/horror **from your investigator**. If a card simpley read "Heal X horror" or "Heal X damage," you can only use it to heal horror or damage **from your investigator**. Cards that allow to heal other investigators or asset will specify that.